# Count(*) returns (rows number - 1) in sql developer(ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get this result in sql developer(emp table):

```
TOTAL       1980       1981      1982     1983
-------- --------- --------- --------- ---------
14            1        10         2        1
```

but I am getting :

```
TOTAL       1980       1981      1982     1983
-------- --------- --------- --------- ---------
13            1        10         2        1
```

Counting on the entire table gives me 14:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMP;
```

Why does the count in this case return 13 not 14 ?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) TOTAL,
SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM HIREDATE),1980,COUNT(*))) "1980",
SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM HIREDATE),1981,COUNT(*))) "1981",
SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM HIREDATE),1982,COUNT(*))) "1982",
SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM HIREDATE),1983,COUNT(*))) "1983"
FROM EMP GROUP BY HIREDATE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) TOTAL,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM HIREDATE) = 1980 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "1980",
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM HIREDATE) = 1981 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "198`",
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM HIREDATE) = 1982 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "1982",
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM HIREDATE) = 1983 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "1983"
FROM EMP;
```

Notes:

- There is no need to `GROUP BY HIREDATE`.  You only seem to want one row of output.
- `DECODE()` is Oracle-specific.  The ANSI standard for conditional expressions is `CASE`.
- You have nested aggregation functions (`COUNT(*)` inside `SUM()`).  This is the cause of your problem.  This version should fix the issue.